# DBAN MD5SUM Hash for Version 2.2.6 (i586)

Tags: hard-drive, security, md5, dban, file-shredding

Found this [forum thread on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dban/forums/forum/208932/topic/3525259), but the MD5SUM Hash is for "dban.bzi", so that doesn't help at all.  I checked elsewhere in the SourceForge forums, but I didn't find anything else.  I also checked the Documentation pages of DBAN, yet there was still nothing on the MD5SUM Hash for Version 2.2.6 of DBAN.  Does anybody know of a resource that maintains the current MD5SUM Hash for DBAN 2.2.6?

Comment: Would you explain a bit more about your specific issue and goals.

Comment: Just finished editing the question.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Uh, what? You went to the trouble of posting all this instead of just creating an internet archive account? You know you can log in to internet archive with an OpenID account, then you don't even need to create anything new.

Comment: No, I wasn't aware that it employed OpenID.  That changes things.  Thanks for letting me know.  As the post below alludes to, I also went to this effort for the sake of data redundancy &amp; so that it's easily accessible via means of search engines (my experience with the Internet Archive is that I have to directly search it for results, as Googling key terms with "Internet Archive" usually results in misnomers - just my experience though, not necessarily ubiquitous).  I'll edit my answer once I finish uploading to the archives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update - 2011/06/06

Not sure if this was available at the time I asked the question, but recent visits to SourceForge have enlightened me to the **availability of MD5 & SHA1 verification hashes on the SourceForge site.**

Here's the link: 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/dban/files/dban/dban-2.2.6/

On the same horizontal line of "dban-2.2.6_i586.iso", just click on the italicized "i" in the grey circle.

For convenience, I'll post the MD5 & SHA1 hashes here:

`cb0a4b6b7cee3342359e9cd6e324138f` (MD5)

`534921ff013f34ded279300eb3851ec707b58475` (SHA1)

As of this writing, DBAN 2.2.6 is still the latest version available.

Alas, I did not upload a record to the Internet Archive; I'm not using the vendor-neutral version of OpenID, so I would have had to create one, and, of course, I refrained from doing so.  I'll admit it, I'm sagaciously lazy ^^

---

While in mid-post of the question, I found this at a [Japanese version of SourceForge](http://fr.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_dban/downloads/dban/dban-2.2.6/dban-2.2.6_i586.iso/).  There are likely mirrors of the site, but I'm going to post the MD5SUM Hash here, since Japan's still in the middle of the tsunami-earthquake-nuclear crisis:

`cb0a4b6b7cee3342359e9cd6e324138f`

For the sake of being clear (and to satisfy my own pedantic nature), here's what I did:

1. I downloaded DBAN Version 2.2.6 from the actual DBAN website
2. Found the MD5SUM at the Japanese SourceForge site
3. Verified by Copy from the official DBAN website against the MD5SUM Hash posted on the Japanese SourceForge site

I'd like to also upload a record of that Japanese SourceForge site (well, just the page with the DBAN MD5SUM Hash) to the [Internet Archive](http://www.archive.org/create/), but I'd rather not set up a new User ID on *another* site, just for something that's going to be a "one-off" event for me (don't use Internet Archive enough to justify an account).  Thus I'm imploring anybody in the SuperUser community, that has an established Log In with the Internet Archive, to do so in behalf of the HDD-wiping community that wants to know that their DBAN copy is legitimate.  If the DBAN project were a little more active (almost a year since last update) & had more Documentation that's well maintained & easily accessible, I wouldn't be making the request (I'm also asking because I'm still working on getting KeePass running on my machine - I'm not in any position to memorize anymore User IDs & Passwords).

Now, I could have left the answer portion alone in the question section, but I figured it would be best to follow the proper StackExchange format.

**Notes**: Based on some material I've reviewed, it seems that SourceForge.jp does not share the same owner as SourceForge.net (**Geeknet, Inc.**), so it seems that they're similar in name & function only.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SourceForge
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SourceForge.JP

Also, the two links immediately above are not anchored (<a href> tag pair) as my rep prevents me from posting more than 2 links per post (Spam Filter, which I'm quite thankful for).